# Trying to calculate frame size of UILabel based on the amount of text for subview of cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

The code below has code that determines the frame size of a UILabel, and I think it does work, however when I place it within my rowAtIndexPath for a UItable I get wonky results.

Perhaps, I dont fully understand how or what the reuseIdentifier does, but I placed the code to calculate the frame only when the cell is nil. What happens is that the heights are calculated only for the first three cells, then it repeats in sequence for the rest of the cells. For example, cell one's height is used for cell four's height.

Maybe someone can point me in the right direction as to how I should setup my calculations.

Thanks!

```
if(cell == nil){

    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                reuseIdentifier:DisclosureButtonCellIdentifier] autorelease];

    //start adding custom subviews to the table cell


    //addSubview for Description
UILabel *descValue = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    NSString *descString = rowData.summary;
    CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(185, 130);
    UIFont *descFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12];
    CGSize descStringSize = [descString sizeWithFont:descFont 
                                   constrainedToSize:maximumSize 
                                       lineBreakMode:descValue.lineBreakMode];
    CGRect descFrame = CGRectMake(125, 60, 185, descStringSize.height);
    descValue.frame = descFrame;

    descValue.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    descValue.font = descFont;
    descValue.tag = kDescriptionValueTag;
    descValue.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    descValue.numberOfLines = 0;

    [cell.contentView addSubview:descValue];
    [descValue release];
}


UILabel *desc = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:kDescriptionValueTag];
    desc.text = rowData.summary;
```

Answer (score 3):

Using NSString UIKit Additions, you can get the width of a string using a particular font:

```
[myString sizeWithFont:myFont];
```

There are several other functions in that Additions set that can help figure out how big a piece of text will be, with different layout options, for single and multi-line text, etc.

The purpose of the reuseIdentifier is to let you reuse a cell -- with particular subviews in particular places -- without the device having to spend the execution time to do all that layout. Definitely more useful back in the iPhone 1 days when the processor was much slower. Until you are more familiar with reuseIdentifiers, I would suggest you just create a new cell every time that function is called.

Each time the OS calls your cellForRowAtIndexPath, you need to fill out the content correctly. Anything that needs to get resized or changed depending on the row should be set.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, I did not try understanding your code completely. That is nearly impossible especially because you close the method with brackets without returning anything but `cellForRowAtIndexPath` which I assume you are referring to, requires the return of a `UITableViewCell` object.

Apparently we are looking only at some fraction of the code.

However, layouting a cell properly is not the full task. You need to tell the table the height of each cell. 
You may want to implement

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

for that task. That method is good if the cell height varies. 
If the cell hight is different from the standard but does not vary from cell to cell then setting of the rowHeight property of the tableView will be sufficient.

I think that in your case the implementation of the method `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is mandatory.

BTW, you may want to look at subclassing the UITableCellView and implement the `layoutSubviews` method in your subclass.

Comment: thanks. What is the reasoning for using layoutSubviews? Yes it is only a portion of the code, the rest is basic tableview code. the cell height is fixed. I want to calculate the height because there will be other uilabels below and I want them to be properly aligned beneath. I just want to know why the cell==nil only executes three times and does not calculate or run for the rest of the cells.

Comment: Well, Adam, it is a bit of guesswork because you do not show all of the code. Assuming that "basic table view" code means, that you executed UITableViewCell before your code then please understand the reusing mechanism of table cells. A cell (along with all its resources as subviews, images) can be reused if it disappears from the screen. If your view is high enough so that only 3 cells can be displayed, for the 4th cell the 1st (now invisible) will be reused. Meaning you will not enter the cell==nil part of your code. You could of course move some of that code out of the if-clause, ...

Comment: ... or you move all that code into a subclass of UITableViewCell. Some of that code may actually go to the cell's initWithStyle method and some of it should move to layoutSubViews. However, I am sure that you can cope with all of that within cellForRowAtIndexPath but that is less sexy. :)

Comment: Just understand that your cell==nil branch is executed only then when a new cell is allocated but not when an existing cell is reused. A Table that never displays more than 3 cells at once - because of their size - does not need to allocate more than 3 cell objects.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show all of your code but usually to implement tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: you start with the following:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // get a cell from the queue of reusable cells, if any
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: DisclosureButtonCellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        // No cell to reuse, need to create a new one
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                 reuseIdentifier:DisclosureButtonCellIdentifier] autorelease];  

        // add cell subviews here      
    }

    // fill in cell content and resize subviews here
    ...

    return cell;
}
```

Once you have created 3 (in your case) cells they get reused as the table scrolls so you don't have to keep creating cells.  The call to dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier will return one of the previously created cells if it was not longer in use (it scrolled off the top or the bottom).